# Consider the equation: $x' = f(t,x)$. Prove that there is a two-way correspondence between the initial and the limits of the solutions.

Tags: integration, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation:
$$x' = f(t,x)$$
wherein,
$$|f(t,x)| \leq \phi(t)x, \forall(t,x) \in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} $$
$$ \int^{\infty}_a\phi(t)\,dt< \infty$$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$. 
If in addition, $f$ satisfying:
$$ |f(t,x) - f(t,y)|\leq \phi(t)|x-y|, \forall(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$$

Prove that there is a two-way correspondence between the initial and the limits of the solutions.

Sorry for the mistakes in the translation into English

Comment: No problem with your English. But what is the meaning of $\int^{\infty}\phi/(t)< \infty$ ? Is it $\int_0^{\infty}\phi(t)\,dt < \infty$ ?

Comment: is $\int_a^{\infty}$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ @HandeBruijn

Comment: Then please improve the mathematics of your post.

Comment: Sorry. I still don't comprehend the expression $\int^{\infty}_a\phi/(t)< \infty$ as being proper mathematics.

Comment: @HandeBruijn there was a typo, just fix it.Sorry.

Comment: Hello! Can you please be more precise about what is the meaning of a "*two-way correspondence between the initial and the limits of the solutions*"? If you have an screenshot or a pic of the problem in its original source, it might be helpful to post it here :-)

Comment: Hello @leo, means that the function is injection and onto, I have no photo because the problem is portugues.Sorry.

Comment: It doesn't matter. There's no problem in posting the original problem in portuguese. Which limits and which initial? Initial conditions, and limits at infinity?

Comment: I have also a hard time undertanding what "a two-way correspondence between the initial and the limits of the solutions" means. Some random observations: If $\phi\geq 0$ then $x' = f(x,t) \leq \phi(t) x \implies$ $\frac{d}{dt}\left[xe^{-\int_0^t\phi(t')dt'}\right] = [x' - \phi x]e^{-\int_0^t\phi(t')dt'} \leq 0$ so  $x(t) \leq x(0) e^{\int_0^t\phi(t')dt'}$. This shows that $x$ is bounded.

Comment: The equation $|f(t,x)| \leq \phi(t) x$ for all $(t,x) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ implies that $\phi(t)=0$ for all $t$ (indeed just apply this equation for $x=-\phi(t)$). So $f(t,x)=0$ always and the differential equation becomes $x'(t)=0$, which means $x(t)$ is a constant for all $t$.  So $x(\infty)=x(0)$, which is an obvious 1-to-1 correspondence.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $|f(t,x)| \leq \phi(t) x$ for all $(t,x) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ implies that $\phi(t)=0$ for all $t$ (indeed just apply this equation for $x=-\phi(t)$). So $f(t,x)=0$ always and the differential equation becomes $x'(t)=0$, which means $x(t)$ is a constant for all $t$.  So $x(\infty)=x(0)$, which is an obvious 1-to-1 correspondence.

Of course, this seems trivial: There are likely some typos in your question that make the *real* question something different than what is given.